# App engine development server not working with --backends

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a long running task that would benefit from running in a backend. However, when I call dev_appserver.py with the --backends option the server no longer works correctly.

I am getting an error page that I never saw before on app engine. And the error seems to be a

The stack trace is really long, but I took a screenshot of the top of the error page:
[image: top of the error page]
And of the bottom:
[image: bottom of the error page]

It seems to be related with the logging module, because the first time that I can see something related with an error in an except clause is in the logging module:

```
 C:\Python27\lib\logging__init__.py in emit(self=<logging.StreamHandler object>, record=<logging.LogRecord object>)
    872             raise
    873         except:
=>  874             self.handleError(record)
    875 
    876 class FileHandler(StreamHandler):
self = <logging.StreamHandler object>, self.handleError = <bound method StreamHandler.handleError of <logging.StreamHandler object>>, record = <logging.LogRecord object>
```

OS is Win7 x64, I have searched for something similar to this and found nothing. Any clues are more than welcome.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that from version 1.8.x on, the `--backends` argument is not necessary (nor supported) since the backends support is automatically available. Running `dev_appserver.py` alone should be sufficent but don't forget to provide `backends.yaml` file.

Comment: thanks @xaralis, this was long before 1.8.0 and I never managed to solve it. The dirty workaround was not using backends on dev. 1.8.0 is great, once they solve the debugging issue.

Answer (score 0):

Error is quite confusing but it does say "illegal argument". The `--backends` argument that you are passing is not one of [available command line arguments for python dev server](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but running dev_appserver --help says that one possible argument is: "--backends                 Run the dev_appserver with backends support (multiprocess mode)." I used that argument because I saw it in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview Where it says "When running dev_appserver.py, pass --backends to enable backends support." So I guess it must be that the dev_appserver doc is a bit outdated.

Comment: I see --backends isn't in the help anymore as of the latest version (1.8.X), but the docs site still lists it.  Is this feature nonexistent?

Comment: Feature has been set to run by default in my opinion. Try running it without the argument while having backends.yaml correctly set up.